# Linkedin versioning Marketing API - isDSC returns True by default

Tags: api, linkedin-api, api-versioning

I'm trying to use Linkedin versioning (the new approach) Marketing API to publish posts on the company page.
I'm following the official docs and trying to use provided example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/posts-api

Here is my request:

```
        content = "x"
        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {self.access_token}",
            "X-Restli-Protocol-Version": "2.0.0",
            "LinkedIn-Version": "202207",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        }
        author = f"urn:li:organization:{self.page_id}"
        data = {
            "author": author,
            "commentary": content,
            "visibility": "PUBLIC",
            "distribution": {
                "feedDistribution": "NONE",
                "targetEntities": [],
                "thirdPartyDistributionChannels": []
            },
            "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
            "isReshareDisabledByAuthor": False,
        }
        response = requests.post("https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts", headers=headers, json=data)
        return response
```

But I get the error:

```
{"errorDetailType":"com.linkedin.common.error.BadRequest","code":"MISSING_REQUIRED_FIELD_FOR_DSC","message":"Field /adContext/dscAdAccount is required when the post is a Direct Sponsored Content, but missing in the request","errorDetails":{"inputErrors":[{"description":"Field /adContext/dscAdAccount is required when the post is a Direct Sponsored Content, but missing in the request","input":{"inputPath":{"fieldPath":"/adContext/dscAdAccount"}},"code":"MISSING_REQUIRED_FIELD_FOR_DSC"}]},"status":400}
```

I don't want to use DSC at all. But cannot disable it since `isDsc` field is read-only.

Comment: How did you solve this issue?